# The formula directly embedded in the sequence expression

Tags: sequences-and-series, notation

My textbook says that sequences and series should be written as {a<sub>n</sub>}. But somewhere else in the same book there is something like this:

$$\{\dfrac{1}{n^2}\}$$

That is putting the formula $a_n=\dfrac{1}{n^2}$ directly into the curly braces indicating sequences. This might be easily confused with the set notation. Could you explain what it means?

Comment: i mean, a sequence of points in some space is a set; it is the image of the function defining the sequence. if it makes it any clearer, other typical notations are $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ or $\{a_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ or $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$. you can replace the symbols $a_n$ with some general formula as well, should make no difference.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to write down a sequence, for example,
$$
  \{a_n\}_{n \in \mathbb N}, \quad (a_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}, \quad (a_n)_{n = 0}^\infty, \quad \langle a_n |n \in \mathbb{N}\rangle.
$$
Other combinations of writing $n \in \mathbb N$ in a subscript or after $|$ exist (though $\{a_n|n \in \mathbb N\}$ is definitely a set). Also, your natural numbers might start at $1$ instead. If you are in a course, you should use what your professor uses. If you are doing math “on your own”, you can use whichever you prefer.

In all of these, you can replace $a_n$ by an explicit term involving $n$ to define an explicit sequence and the placement of $n \in \mathbb N$ makes it clear that you’re still talking about a sequence.

Now, mathematicians are lazy and the ($n \in \mathbb N$)-part is often abundantly clear from the context, so we shorten the notations to
$$
   \{ a_n \}, \quad (a_n), \quad \langle a_n \rangle.
$$

These now look a bit like a one-element set or a one-element tuple. However, when the context makes it obvious that we are talking about sequences, this is fine. After all, it’s humans who are reading the text, not computers. (If it is *not* obvious from context, the short forms are bad mathematical writing, though.)

Even in the shortened forms, replacing $a_n$ by something explicit is fine, provided the meaning is clear.

One trick to decipher what is meant is to look at free variables. If I write, say, $\{ n^2 \}$ and I never specified $n$ to be a specific number (i.e. $n$ appears to be a free variable), then this term is not well-defined in a strict sense. So you (the reader) need to mentally add a specification of $n$ somewhere. It is very uncommon to leave off the “such that”-part in set-builder notation, so I probably left off the ($n \in \mathbb N$)-part of my  sequence and I really mean $\{ n^2 \}_{n \in \mathbb N}$. (Admittedly, this is something you need to learn from experience.) On the other hand, if $n$ is specified in the context, I probably mean the one-element set consisting of $n^2$ for that specific value of $n$.

In short:

- If I write “Consider $\{n^2\}$. …”, I probably mean the sequence.
- If I write “Consider $\{n^2\}$ where $n$ is the number of letters in my name. …”, I probably mean the set.